# Inserting data via jquery/coldfusion cfc

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc

I have the following code that adds a string of content to a div from a textarea (which works) and then its meant to add that data into a database by calling a cfc

That section doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddContent()
{
    var text1 = $("#chatText").text();
    var text2 = $("#newChatText1").val();
    $("#chatText").html(text1 + "<br />" + text2);

    var postData = {
        str_name: #GetLastChat.str_Name#,
        int_ChatID: #url.int_ChatID#,
        str_Content: text2
                    };

    var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "./chat_process.cfc?method=Function_UpdateChat",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify( postData )
    });     

}
</script>

Chat Conversation<br>
<div id="chatText" class="chatText" style="border:1px; border-style:solid; height:200px; width:500px;">
Welcome <cfoutput>#GetLastChat.str_Name#</cfoutput>
```

```
New Message<br />
<textarea id="newChatText1" rows="3" cols="50" class="chatinput"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="AddContent()">
```

The postdata and ajaxresponse sections dont work but no obvious error - can anyone help?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: You need to wrap `#GetLastChat.str`_Name# and `#url.int_ChatID#` in `postData` structure with `<cfoutput>`.

Comment: arggh! Thanks Pankaj - stupid error. That's got me further :)

Comment: ok - stuck again :)

How can I get that data in a cfquery to insert?

Comment: I believe for that you would need to share your cfc code especially the function `Function_UpdateChat`.

Comment: Have you considered doing things the easy way and simply posting the form?

Comment: cfc code:-

 <cffunction name="Function_UpdateChat" access="remote">
 
  <cfset requestBody = toString(getHttpRequestData().content) />
 
  <cfset ArrayOfStructs = deserializeJson(requestBody)>
  
  <cfloop collection="#ArrayOfStructs#" item="x">
   
   <cfquery datasource="#request.dsn#" name="insertChat">
    INSERT INTO tbl_ChatConversation(int_ChatID, str_Name, str_Content, dtm_DateEntered)
    VALUES(#int_ChatID#, '#str_Name#', '#str_Content#', #now()#)
   </cfquery>
  </cfloop>
 </cffunction>

Answer (score 0):

Paul

The insertion itself should be pretty straightforward using the standard CFQUERY tag such as:

```
<CFQUERY name="ChatInsert" datasource="«yourDatasource»">
    INSERT INTO «YourTable» (chatId, username, chat_text)
    VALUES (
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#arguments.int_ChatID#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.str_name#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.str_Content#">
    )
</CFQUERY>
```

Comment: Hi Trollhammer - thanks for your input. Doing the query is fine but its getting the data into a correct format first - see above....

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your javascript. You're stringifying your post data so your cfc is not getting the arguments via post.

Correct code will be:

```
data: postData
```